# Save PNG export settings?

Tags: export

Is there a way to save those settings? I always forget to set them right and then have to go back and rerender a dozen images.

[image]

Comment: Are you saving the image after the Render?

Comment: yes ... I did not thought of using the output tab instead... I'm getting old.

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank Blender file with this settings and save it as your template. Then each time copy the file and paste it to your project location and work on the duplicated file.

Comment: whatever you do, don't do this!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still looking for the solution, here is the correct way how to do this:

1. Open a new file
2. Set your desired defaults in `Output Properties` -> `Output`-Region (see attached image) and save your blender startup file via `File` -> `Defaults` -> `Save Startup File`. This will keep all your changes/settings of your currently opened file as defaults to load when you open a new one. Tested with Blender >= 3.6

[image]